# Return CheckBox True False Status With jQuery Map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating dynamic **CheckBoxes** using `jQuery` and by default, those are set to false status. Something as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" value="false" />
```

So you can see no value or id is assigned there. Is it possible to just retrieve the true/false based on **CheckBox** checked/unchecked status something as follows using `jQuery` mapping?

```
string = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (i, elements) {
    return elements; //Here the elements like true or false, instead of elements.value
});

alert(string.join(','));
```

**Expected Output**: true, false, false, true (Based on user selection)

Comment: Do you want to have the `value` for all checked checkbox? **OR** the checked state of all checkboxes (like in Mohammad answer)?

Answer (score 0):

The `.checked` property return check/uncheck status of checkbox. So you need to use it.

```
var string = $('[type=checkbox]').map(function (i, elements) {
    return elements.checked; 
}).toArray().join(",");
```

Also you can simplify the code

```
var string = $(':checkbox').map((i,ele) => ele.checked).toArray().join(",");
```

```js
var string = $(':checkbox').map((i,ele) => ele.checked).toArray().join(",");
console.log(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" />
```

Comment: Sorry I thought I was editing my post actually. I rolled back to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checked property.

```js
const string = Array.from($('input[type=checkbox]')).map(function(element) {
  return element.checked; //Here the elements like true or false, instead of elements.value
});

console.log(string.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" checked/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var checkboxes = [];

function createDynamicCheckBoxes() {
  if (checkboxes.length != 0)
    return;
  var numberOfBoxes = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; i++) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("value", "false");
    
    var number = document.createElement('label');
    number.innerText = "(" + (checkboxes.length+1) + ") ";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(number);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(checkbox);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    
    checkboxes.push(checkbox);
  }
}

function logValues(){
  for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    console.log("Checkbox (" + (i+1) + ") is set to " + checkboxes[i].checked);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createDynamicCheckBoxes()">Generate Checkboxes</button>

<button onclick="logValues()">Log Values of Checkboxes</button>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

This is a pure JavaScript based snippet. You can do something like this!